# Given the composition of two permutations $\beta \gamma$ and $\gamma \beta$ find $\beta$ and $\gamma$

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations

> Given $\beta$, $\gamma \in S_4$ such that $\beta \gamma = (1,4,3,2)$, $\gamma \beta = (1,2,4,3)$ and $\beta(1)=4$ determine $\beta$ and $\gamma$.

I'm new to permutation groups and I have no clue about how to tackle this kind of questions. I have tried composing the permutations and trying to solve the system for the unknowns but I've failed to get anywhere. I'm not looking for a specific answer to this problem, i just want some tips or hints on how to approach this kind of problems.

Thanks in advance

Comment: As shown by the user azif00 below this can be solved by starting with $\beta(1)=4$ and solving from there. However, if this were to be a problem with much larger permutation groups is there a different aproach that skips this long process?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just unpack the data.

We have the following:
$$
\beta(\gamma(1)) = 4, \quad \beta(\gamma(4)) = 3, \quad \beta(\gamma(3)) = 2, \quad \beta(\gamma(2)) = 1, \\
\gamma(\beta(1)) = 2, \quad \gamma(\beta(2)) = 4, \quad \gamma(\beta(4)) = 3, \quad \gamma(\beta(3)) = 1.
$$
Since $\beta(1) = 4$, from the first equation of the second line we find that $\gamma(4) = 2$, and then the second equation of the first line gives us $\beta(2) = 3$. Now, from the second equation of the second line, $\gamma(3) = 4$, so…

Can you continue from here?

Comment: So it's all about starting from that first condition they give and then solving the rest?

Comment: I'm not saying this is *the* way to solve it. It's just the first thing that came to my mind.

Comment: And what if it was a bigger group of permutations where doing it by hand would be impossible. Is there any other way to solve this?

Comment: I don't know. Since this is very mechanical, you could make a try in your favorite programming language that does it for you.